# NAO's eyes remain white (don't turn to blue/green) after ending a program

Tags: nao-robot, choregraphe

I made an app which enables NAO answering according to user input. The app runs well and exits without errors. However, after exiting the app, NAO's eyes remain white. It still listen and answer things in the basic channel properly. The eyes just don't turn to blue when it's listening and gree when it's recognizing. 
Any ideas how to solve it? The eye color indication is highly usuful.

Answer (score 1):

Do you ask explicitly to deactivae the visual feedback in the Speech Recognition / Dialog box ?

Try calling this method at the end of your apps:

```
asr = ALProxy( "ALSpeechRecognition" )
ast.setVisualExpression( True )
```

Comment: No, the visual feedback is activated in the speech recog. I don't know how to deactivate the visual feedback in the dialog box. Indeed, the visual feedback works well when running the app, but not after the app ends.